# Can an extension for VS Code be installed to Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

There is a great extension for VS Code, Bracket Pair Colorizer, can I somehow install it for Visual Studio? Or maybe there is an analog for Visual Studio, or a very similar extension? I would be grateful for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Viasfora](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomasRestrepo.Viasfora) extension for VS 2019 supports [Rainbow Braces](https://github.com/tomasr/viasfora/wiki/Rainbow-Braces).